# Python web scraping comments from dynamic website, without selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, python-requests, screen-scraping

I have to scrape comments from dynemic website. I know how to do it using selenium, but as we  all know selenium is heavy and slow for server side application. Is it possible to do the same with just `requests` library or something like `httpx`?

Currently I have the following selenium code:

```
# instantiate options 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
 
# run browser in headless mode 
options.headless = True 
 
# instantiate driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService( 
    ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) 
 
# load website 
url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/118158324/feedbacks'  # product id 
 
# get the entire website content 
driver.get(url) 

time.sleep(1) 

for i in range(0, 10): #35 scrolls is something like 300 comments, 10 scrolls to 120-130 comments
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
  time.sleep(0.4)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

reviews = []
for i in soup.find_all("li", class_="comments__item feedback j-feedback-slide"):
    try:
      reviews.append((i.find_all("p", class_="feedback__text")[-1]).text)
    except IndexError as e:
       pass
```

Or is there a way to speed up selenium on the vps server? I know that headless java browsers can do it (ex.  [htmlunit](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io) )

I have tried to use requests but because of dynemical loading it only returns basic html.

```
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

However, I found that loading of the comments is happening via this link: [example](https://feedbacks1.wb.ru/feedbacks/v1/159664042). But I have now idea how to find this 159664042 number from the link as it is different depending on product and has no correlation with product id....